# Objective-C で JSON のやり取りをする 同期通信 をする方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

はじめまして。

Objective-C での同期通信処理で JSON ファイルのやりとりを行いたいのですが、
具体的にどの方法が良いのかわかりません。

`AFNetworking`を使わない方法が知りたいです。

Google で検索するも色々なやり方があり迷ってます。

ご教授、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 皆様、ありがとうございます。
なんとか解決出来ました。

Answer (score 3):

幾つかあるので選び方だけ。

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
```

はメインスレッドで実行すると、処理をブロックします。

[dataWithContentsOfURLのReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:)には

> Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

と書かれていて、ネットワークにあるデータを取得するために使うべきではありません。

[NSURLDownload](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/)は、ファイルを直接ローカルに書き込む時に利用します。
[Geekなページ:NSURLDownload](http://www.geekpage.jp/programming/macosX-network/NSURLDownload-1.php)あたりがわかりやすいです。

[NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)は、NSURLConnectionで必要だった面倒臭い実装をカプセル化してくれるクラスです。iOS7以降ではこちらを利用するべきです。
[NSURLSession のまとめ](http://qiita.com/aKentaKoyama/items/96a979ab3a140e7b39ec)が参考になります。

[NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html)は、色々と細かく実装したい場合に利用できますが、基本的にはNSURLSessionで事足りると思います。

可能であれば、[AppleドキュメントのURL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)をお読みください。どんな時に何を選べばいいか、とても詳しく書かれています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決出来ました。

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じじゃないですかね。

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.physics.leidenuniv.nl/json/news.php"]];

NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSMutableData *responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[responseData appendData:data];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Answer (score 2):

簡単なのはNSData#dataWithContentsOfURL:です。

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

JSONのデコードは別途NSJSONSerialization等を使います。